# relative path to imported file in LaTeX

Tags: latex, relative-path, tex

I am currently reworking a set of slides to teach students at an university, of course the files are written in LaTeX. Too increase modularity, I want to include files relative to a base file, which will be imported by other files. So suppose I have the following structure:

```sh
|-- document.tex
`-- module
    `-- a
        |-- base.tex
        `-- listings
            `-- test.java
```

Now I want to import `test.java` inside `base.java` by referring to the relative path `listings/test.java`. Is there a way to then import `base.tex` into `document.tex`? Or can I at least extend the relative path `listings/test.java` to the new parent document `document.tex`, e.g. `module/a/listings/test.java`?
I am displaying listings by using `minted` which is unfortunately not affected by the `import` package.

Comment: if your file names are unique, I would just add the top most directory to your `TEXINPUTS` variable and latex will find them without giving any paths at all

Comment: Sadly no. I want to hide the implementation of the module from it's user if you want to say so. The names aren't unique at all.

Comment: Can you add suitable test files to your question? Maybe the `import` package can help?

Answer (score 4):

I have figured it out.

To effectively recreate the secret principle of OOP you have to use the package `currfile` which has the `\currfiledir` command, which is like `pwd` in bash.
It only works in via `\input` or `\include` loaded files, not by using `import` or anything else. It also does not work with the `fragile` option activated.

In this manner, you may create a module, which is relative to it's base file, not the one your document starts in.